# FastAPI OAuth2 Scope

Tags: python, authentication, permissions, fastapi

I have a system which has role based access system.

When the API is called, first the user is authenticated, then I further verify if the user has an access to the endpoint before actually calling the endpoint.

Here is an example for the system:

```
WRITE = {"all": "write_access"} # this is used in user access verification method
READ = {"all": "read_access"} # this is used in user access verification method

ACCESS = {
    # Administrator has every access to every endpoint.
    "Administrator": WRITE,

    # Basic User
    # Restricted access to endpoints
    # Can switch ownership.
    # e.g. A basic user has only READ access to endpoint_1.
    "Basic": {
        "endpoint_1": READ,
        "endpoint_2": WRITE,
        ...
        "endpoint_n": READ
    },
    "Premium": {
        ... 
    }
```

I was reading the FastAPI documentation here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/. FastAPI scopes allows more fine-grained permission system, that restricts access to the endpoints. It seems like the way it works is we give scopes directly to each endpoint. Thus when API calls hit the endpoint, we check if the calling user has correct scope to access the endpoint. I believe this is a bit different from how I'm currently handling the user access verification, where instead of giving scope to each method, I attach the accesses directly to each user type and have a custom method dedicated to check the user verification. In this case, would FastAPI Oauth2 scope be a good choice for my purpose? I'm currently not using FastAPI security or dependencies for authentication of JWT, but have my own internal authentication workflow. I would like to set up a more fine-grained permission system and as I'm moving my system to FastAPI, it would be helpful if I could benefit from built-in functionality which is scope in this case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I'm just learning about scopes as well, but from my reading of https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/ the FastAPI scopes implementation is absolutely a good choice for fine-grained permissions control when using FastAPI.

In general, using the FastAPI security schemes and support is a great choice, at the very least when you are issuing your own tokens. I'm finding it's not trivial to implement support for tokens issued by Azure (but I'm not finished with that yet), but in your own system I really think it's a no-brainer to use the ready-made classes from FastAPI for this purpose.

What scopes allow you to do is specify one or more scopes to be required for any operation in the service, whether that's just access to the end-point, or any dependency declared down the chain. In this way you can specify as many scopes as you like, where you like, per endpoint, or related to any other call that an endpoint makes, providing a way to declare the required scopes where they are used.

Then, FastAPI provides a class, `SecurityScopes` which can be placed as a parameter to your end-points, and this class then has some "magic", in that it collects all the required scopes for that endpoint dependency chain, making it simple to check the user has all necessary scopes before you enter the actual end-point code.

On that page that you were reading it says:

> Because the SecurityScopes will have all the scopes declared by
> dependants, you can use it to verify that a token has the required
> scopes in a central dependency function, and then declare different
> scope requirements in different path operations. They will be checked
> independently for each path operation.

I would recommend you read the [FastAPI advanced OAuth2 security guide](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/) in detail and all this will become clear to you.

I think the question about attaching scopes to the user types instead of the methods is a bit of confusion, because actually you need to do *both*, and this is not a problem either.

So you will declare the scopes *required* for the various operations and end-points as described, and then you will also assign *available* scopes to each user that logs in. Then the permissions checking operation can be dealt with as described above, most conveniently using the `SecurityScopes` class.

Furthermore, if you are using the OpenAPI swagger docs for testing (by making test requests from the OpenAPI docs page) then you are also given the chance to check which scopes you want to log in with, so you can easily test what happens with your code when you have or don't have certain scopes.

To address your dictionary of access types that you give in the question, moving to FastAPI scopes will mean you re-organise your permissions declarations. They won't be centralised in a single dictionary, they will be declared at the points of use, but I think this is an improvement. You don't have to use scopes when moving to FastAPI, nor do you have to use scopes even if you're using the FastAPI security schemes, but it makes sense to do so.

If I'm reading your code right you have four different scopes that you will use, and each user will be assigned one or more of these scopes:

```
["all", "Basic", "Premium", "Administrator"]
```

So a "Premium" user would have scopes "all", "Basic" *and* "Premium". A "Basic" user would only have "all" and "Basic". An administrator would have all the scopes.

Then each endpoint or operation that requires permission would add as a `Security` dependency the single particular scope that you've determined is required for access. So for instance, only admin users will have "Administrator" scope and simply applying "Administrator" scope to an end-point will automatically exclude all other users.

`Security` is just like `Depends`, except it includes a list of scopes. It doesn't even seem to do anything with those scopes, except make them available to `Security` for the checking operation when that's performed on the dependency chain.

Your permissions approach is not actually very fine-grained at all. If you *really* want fine-grained permissions, and you want to make modifying the permissions scheme easier, you would add a lot more scopes that relate to the operations and end-points rather than the user-types. Then you can assign a number of different scopes to each user type as appropriate, and you can start making new user types, and possibly let go of user types altogether and instead start giving users a set of default scopes initially, based on their initial user type, and possibly let them start buying individual additional scopes to level up, or whatever you want to do.

*This has been a wordy, code-less answer, to an old question that you probably don't need answering anymore, but I just thought I would answer this by way of providing an intro to scopes in FastAPI for users like me who are just encountering it. Perhaps you could answer the question as well with what you ended-up doing?*

Answer (score 0):

you can use Scope or FastApi advance dependencies.

[fastapi advance dependencies](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/advanced-dependencies/)

and create a class like RollChecker with **call**  method and restrict the role based on requirement.